# Get by Id when Id is in another collection's document using C# and MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have two collections: Networks and UserNetworks.

In the userNetworks collection I have a userId as Id field and array of networks Ids that belongs to it.

I want to run a query which returns all the networks from Networks collection where networkId is in the given UserId's networks array.

I really want to avoid two queries, one to get the list of networks Ids and the other to fetch the networks themselves. I can't find a decent answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you looking for is called a join and MongoDB doesn't support joins. You can't do what you want in a single query.

You can do a "join on client" by going through one collection each documet at a time and querying the second collection. Or you can load one (or both) collection to the client instead of going back and forth.

Comment: its not Join, join is to retrieve data from 2 collections and display it, i just want to give a source for the search

Comment: @OriRefael It doesn't matter if you display it or not. Join is to combine multiple tables (or collections) in a single query.

Comment: so, just to be clear. the only option i have for a single userId is fetch its network in a query and then in a new query i should be all networks where networkId in first-query-result?

Comment: @OriRefael somewhat. If these collections aren't too big you can query one or both into memory and do the search instead of going back and forth to the db.